# grep not writing to file

Tags: linux, bash, grep, redhat, tail

I am in my home directory and am giving a path to two different files that I want to tail.  Each file I am grepping for 2 variables.  my issue is that this script is not writing to the saveFile.txt for some reason.  the saveFile.txt is in the same directory as the script I am running.

```
#!/bin/sh
tail -f <path1> -f <path2> | egrep -i --line-buffered '<variable1>|<variable2>' > saveFile.txt
```

For an added bonus, is there a way to add spacing to output that is thrown into the file through the same script?  I have been told it maybe easier just to write this in Ruby or Python haha.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the `egrep` is producing output on `stdout`? can you try without writing to file to see if results are there?

Comment: Do you really have everything in one line as shown here?

Comment: I tried doing a single tail and single egrep w/o writing to a file and it was giving me output.

Comment: don't you want >> not >

Comment: you put variable1 and variable2 in single quotes - is this intended?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:

```
tail -f ./listener/alert/log.xml ./listener/trace/listener.log  | grep -P --line-buffered '[A-z]+' | tee ~/foo.txt
```

note: tail doesn't need the multiple -f args. I'm using perl regex in grep with -P flag. And, finally, I like to see the output on the console as well as send it to a file so I use `tee`.

Comment: Just to make sure Im understanding the man pages on the use of tee, it is the same as using '> saveFile.txt' except it also shows the output?  And Im sorry if its a silly question but why use './' before the text file? Thanks!

Comment: (1) Yes, tee forks the output sending it to the console AND to a file. Handy. It is the same as >>, meaning it continually appends to the file. (2) I'm using relative paths in my example, so the dot slash simply means to start the path in the current directory where the tail command is executed. You could just as easily use an absolute path e.g. /var/log.